# ApiMethod with inheritance GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, inheritance, methods

I would just know if inheritance is supported in Google Cloud Endpoints methods. Here is the scenario:
I have an interface :

```
 public interface A { 
   public String getSomething();
 }
```

and a class that implements that interface :

```
public class B implements A {
  public String getSomething(){
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

In my class annotated with @Api I wold have a method like this :

```
@ApiMethod()
public void submitStatistic(A statistic)
```

Then when I generate the client library the B class is not generated but only the interface A is transformed in a class that is available to client side. Is there something to force in some way the transformation of class B ? and also to maintain the inheritance between this classes ?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses#Inheritance

and

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/inheritance.html

Looks like you may need to include a couple extra lines to get it to work over normal Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I read them but it seems that they talk only about the persistence of entities while I want that the model is copied in the client side respecting its hierarchy.